# Ghost4j multi threading not working

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, ubuntu, ghostscript

I used ghost4j 0.5.1 in a web application project which is deployed to Tomcat server in an Ubuntu host. I was able to generate images from PDF when I was not using multi threading. But when I am trying to use multithreading it does not render the PDF files into image files. In Windows, same code was running successfully. Here is my sample code.

```
    PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
    document.load(new File(sourcePath + "/" + fileName));
    // create renderer
    SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();
    renderer.setResolution(resolution);
    renderer.setMaxProcessCount(10);

    List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);

    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        ImageIO.write(
                (RenderedImage) images.get(i),
                "png",
                new File(destPath + "/"
                        + fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."))
                        + ".jpg"));
    }
```

I checked file paths and file paths are also correct. Can anyone please suggest me a way to solve this issue?

Comment: You don't appear to be using Ghostscript's multi-threading there at all. Ghost4j isn't part of Ghostscript so I'm not able to help you with it (and I don't speak Java either so your code is impenetrable, sorry). If you can reformulate the question so that it uses Ghostscript from the command line I could probably help more. It would also be useful to know what version of Ghostscript you are using, on what platofrm, where you got it from, and whether it has been compiled thread-safe. My guess is you are using a version of Ghostscript which has not been compiled for thread safety.

Comment: @Kens I am using Ghostscript 9.10 version in Ubuntu. How to check whether a Ghostscript installation is compiled for thread safety or not?

Comment: I think, basically, you can't. However, unless you compiled it yourself I think its probably safe to assume that it isn't thread safe. You can spawn multiple heavyweight processes safely,  but if you use a shared object then you can only use one thread, unless the library is compiled as thread safe. However, the Windows build isn't compiled thread safe either, so I'm kind of surprised that would work.